# Complete OpenIDConnect auth when requesting via Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, openid, openid-connect, identityserver3

The normal OpenIDConnect server works like:

- You go to `a.com/secure-resource`
- You get a `302` back from the server
- Your browser handles it and sends you to the identity server
- You login there
- It sends you back to `a.com` via a `POST`
- You get logged in on `a.com` and get `a.com/secure-resource` back on your browser.

**However** I have a scenario that I'm trying to solve but I need your help.

- The user is already logged in on idServer
- The user is logged in on `a.com`
- The user is NOT logged in on `b.com`
- We need to send an ajax call to web server `b.com` (from another domain `a.com`)
- `b.com` is configured to use OpenIDConnect.
- But because the request to `b.com` is via Ajax, user cannot be redirected normally to idServer. (all we get in response is a `302`)

We can go ahead and handle the 302 via Ajax (I'm still not sure whether that would work, security-wise).

**BUT**

Is there any scenario in IdentityServer/OpenIDConnect that is designed for these situations?

Answer (score 3):

With IdentityServer in this scenario you setup server `b.com` to use Bearer Token Authentication, you then need to use the access token provided for a.com in the headers of your Ajax call

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'http://b.com',
     headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + Your Access Token
         }
     })
```

The JavaScript IdentityServer Client samples have ways of retrieving the Token from the Identity Server, [see here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients)

In a controller you can get the user and the token like this

```
// Get the claims values
var token= (User as ClaimsPrincipal).Claims
               .Where(c => c.Type == "access_token")
               .Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
```

In other parts of your application you can use this

```
//Get the current claims principal
var identity = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;

// Get the claims values
var token = identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "accept_token")
               .Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Promising answer! The only thing is that `a.com` authenticate the user on the server side (not by javascript). Is there a way to get the token there? Do you sugges getting the a.com server to write it's token on a cookie to be picked up by javascript?

Comment: Yes, server `a.com` could store it into a cookie

Comment: awesome, but how can `a.com` intercept the token during the authentication? (I'm doing it in OWIN)

Comment: I added some code to show how to access the claims and the token

Comment: cool! I didn't know `access_token` is just another Claim type!

Comment: Will Single Logout work in this case? for app b.com the Idp doesn't actually know about the session... Bearer authentication doesn't call the server itself